# Visual Studio 2019 Setup project - include Access Database Engine Redistributable 2016/2010

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2019, setup-project

I'm trying to create Setup project for my application in Visual Studio 2019 that needs Access Database Engine 2010/2016.
I tried following all the information that I could find on web but no success.
I created `accessdatabaseegine` folder under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages` and put appropriate Product.xml in it and `Eula.rtf` & `Package.xml` in `en` folder underneath `accessdatabaseegine` folder. I used Eula.rtf after trying license.txt which didn't work.
But in spite of doing this,  MS Access Database Engine installation option would not show up in prerequisite menu on visual studio 2019 set up project. Tried with VS 2017 as well with no result.
Any suggestions and other application installer that may help achieve this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think if you put the customized bootstrapper folder into this path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages`, then it should be listed here: right-click the Setup project > Properties > click `Prerequisites…` button and you will see it listed in `Choose which prerequisites to install` window.

[image]